# Training LSTM Model in R and reshaping the array

Tags: python, r, lstm, prediction, forecasting

I am hoping someone can help me. I am trying to design an LSTM model in R for carrying out predictions and forecasting.

This is my loop:

```
 for (i in 1:length(dates)) { date <- dates[i]

     # Check if it is a bank holiday (August 28, 2023) and handle predictions differently 

     if (date == as.Date("2023-08-28")) { predicted_data[i, 3:(length(time_slots) + 2)] <- NA 
    # Assign NA for the time slots on the bank holiday 
     } else 

    if (weekdays(date) != "Sunday") { 

     # Prepare the data for LSTM training 

     x_train <- filtered_data[, c("call_day_of_week_name", "call_month", "call_year",
 
"call_hour")] y_train <- filtered_data[, "Calls Count"] 

     # Normalize the data (if needed) 
     # Apply any required data preprocessing steps (e.g., scaling, normalization, encoding, etc.) 
     # Reshape the data for LSTM training 

     x_train <- array_reshape(unlist(x_train), dim = c(nrow(x_train), 1, 1)) 

     # Build and train the LSTM model 
     model <- keras_model_sequential() 

     model %>% layer_lstm(units = 64, input_shape = c(4, 1)) 
    %>% layer_dense(units = 1) model %>% compile(loss = 'mean_squared_error', 
    optimizer = 'adam') 

     model %>% fit(x_train, y_train, epochs = 100, batch_size = 32) 

     # Prepare the data for predictions 

     x_pred <- matrix(c(weekdays(date), date$month, date$year, date$hour), nrow = 1) 

     x_pred <- array_reshape(x_pred, dim = c(1, 4, 1)) 

     # Perform predictions for the time slots
 
     predictions <- model %>% predict(x_pred) 

     # Store the predictions in the corresponding time slots of the predicted_data dataframe predicted_data[i, 3:(length(time_slots) + 2)] <- predictions } }
```

I have tried to change the reshape line of code several times and here are my attempts.

x_train <- array_reshape(x_train, dim = c(length(x_train), 1, 4))

Error feed back:

Apologies for the confusion. It appears that the dimensions of x_train and y_train are indeed matching, with both having 113,472 rows.
Given that x_train has 4 fields ("call_hour", "call_day_of_week_name", "call_month", "call_year"), and y_train has 1 field ("Calls Count"), the dimensions seem correct.
The error you encountered might be due to another part of the code. I recommend checking the remaining code and the specific line that throws the error. It's possible that the issue lies in the model architecture or the input data passed to the model.
If you can provide the specific line of code that triggers the error, I can assist you further in troubleshooting the issue.

Next try:

x_train <- array_reshape(x_train, dim = c(nrow(x_train), 1, 4))

Error:

Error in py_call_impl(callable, call_args$unnamed, call_args$named) :
ValueError: Must pass 2-d input. shape=(113472, 1, 4)
Run `reticulate::py_last_error()` for details.

New Try:

x_train <- reticulate::array_reshape(x_train, dim = c(nrow(x_train), 4))

Error in py_call_impl(callable, call_args$unnamed, call_args$named) :
ValueError: Must pass 2-d input. shape=(113472, 1, 4)
Run `reticulate::py_last_error()` for details.

New Try:

x_train <- reshape(x_train, dim = c(nrow(x_train), 4))

Feedback:

Error in py_call_impl(callable, call_args$unnamed, call_args$named) :
ValueError: Must pass 2-d input. shape=(4, 1, 113472)
Run `reticulate::py_last_error()` for details.

New Try:

x_train <- array_reshape(unlist(x_train), dim = c(nrow(x_train), 1, 1))

Error:

Error in py_call_impl(callable, call_args$unnamed, call_args$named) :
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 453888 into shape (113472,1,1)
Run `reticulate::py_last_error()` for details.

Can anyone help me please? I really appreciate this.